# Imac keyboard malfunctions at startup

Tags: keyboard, imac, login

Imac having odd problem.  Entering password at bootup, the computer does not respond to keystroke (usb keyboard), until it's been tapped multiple (but not consistent) number of times, then it will spit out several iterations of the same letter (but not as many as taps).  Very difficult to backspace to correct.  When that frustrating process finally gets a password, the computer works fine.  After some use (a day or so) the keyboard starts not responding in a similar fashion. Rebooting is necessary.

We swapped out keyboards, disconnected any bluetooth devices that had at one time been connected. Run techtools and disk utility, no issues appear. Any clues/suggestions?

kt

Answer (score 1):

I would reset both your PRAM/NVRAM and your SMC. See below for instructions.

**Reset your PRAM/NVRAM**

Older Macs had what's called Parameter RAM (PRAM), newer Macs use Non-Volatile Random-Access Memory (NVRAM). It may be worth you also resetting this. Here’s how to:

1. **Shut down your machine.** Yes, a full shut down, not just logging out.
2. **Press the <kbd>power button</kbd> *and then* press the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> keys.** You have to make sure you press these keys before the gray screen appears or it won’t work.
3. **Hold those keys down** until your Mac reboots again and you here the startup chime.
4. **Let go of the keys and let your Mac reboot normally.**

**Note:** When you log back in you ***may*** need to readjust some of your system preferences (e.g. mouse speed, time and date/timezone, etc).

**Reset the SMC**

Your computer's System Management Controller (SMC) can also be reset. The instructions for doing this on an iMac are:

1. Shut down your computer
2. Unplug it from the power
3. Press and hold the <kbd>power button</kbd> for 5 seconds
4. Plug it back in and turn it on.